# Sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

My Flask app (PostgreSQL database) is working fine in local. I pushed my code to server and there I tried to `run.py db migrate`, it throws these errors

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 11, in <module>
    create_app().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 412, in run
    result = self.handle(sys.argv[0], sys.argv[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/__init__.py", line 383, in handle
    res = handle(*args, **config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_script/commands.py", line 216, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_migrate/__init__.py", line 239, in upgrade
    command.upgrade(config, revision, sql=sql, tag=tag)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/command.py", line 174, in upgrade
    script.run_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/script/base.py", line 407, in run_env
    util.load_python_file(self.dir, 'env.py')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/util/pyfiles.py", line 93, in load_python_file
    module = load_module_py(module_id, path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/alembic/util/compat.py", line 79, in load_module_py
    mod = imp.load_source(module_id, path, fp)
  File "migrations/env.py", line 87, in <module>
    run_migrations_online()
  File "migrations/env.py", line 72, in run_migrations_online
    connection = engine.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2018, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 72, in __init__
    if connection is not None else engine.raw_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2104, in raw_connection
    self.pool.unique_connection, _connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2078, in _wrap_pool_connect
    e, dialect, self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    exc_info
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 199, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2074, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 318, in unique_connection
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 713, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 480, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 1151, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 323, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 449, in __init__
    self.connection = self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool.py", line 607, in __connect
    connection = self.__pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/strategies.py", line 97, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 385, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 164, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, async=async)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  parameter "listen_addresses" cannot be changed without restarting the server
```

`run.py db init` worked fine and successfully created the migrations folder in the server.

My main app code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')

rest_api = Api(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)

from app import routes

Compress(app)
assets = Environment(app)
define_assets(assets)
cache = Cache(app,config={'CACHE_TYPE': 'simple'})

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)
```

and `run.py` code

```
from flask_failsafe import failsafe


@failsafe
def create_app():
    from app import manager
    return manager

from app import app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    create_app().run()
```

Comment: Have you tried to restart PostgreSQL?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with a `sudo.

```
sudo run.py db migrate
```

I know it is weird but yes, sudo did the trick