# How to access localhost from another computer on same network?

Tags: python, flask, networking, flask-restful

I have written some flask api and running on http://localhost:5000/ .
I want to test those api's from other computer which is connected in a same network.
I am using windows 10.

What I have tried yet:

1. I did ipconfig/all and got ipv4 address . Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:-> IPv4 Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX(Preferred).
2. Ran XX.XX.XXX.XXX:5000 , but got "This site can’t be reached".

Comment: You can do `app.run("0.0.0.0", port=5000)` and from another machine, go to the server machines ip:5000 to access it.

Comment: @HarshalParekh how do i get server machines ip?

Comment: ... server machine is your machine

Comment: Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:-> IPv4 Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX(Preferred).? is that one

Comment: @HarshalParekh "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address" got this error by changing localhost to 0.0.0.0

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023052/configure-flask-dev-server-to-be-visible-across-the-network

Answer (score 3):

Open the port 5000 in your machine. Follow the steps:

1. Navigate to Control Panel, System and Security and Windows Firewall.
2. Select Advanced settings and highlight Inbound Rules in the left pane.
3. Right click Inbound Rules and select New Rule.
4. Add the port you need to open and click Next(5000 in your case).
5. Add the protocol (TCP or UDP) and the port number into the next window and click Next.
6. Select Allow the connection in the next window and hit Next.
7. Select the network type as you see fit and click Next.
8. Name the rule something meaningful and click Finish.

Then try to access through `<your ip>:5000`

sample code is as follows:

```
import flask

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Test Data</p>"

app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

and run your application through cmd as `python api.py` where `api.py` is the file name

Comment: i followed all steps but still getting connection refused .

Comment: try <your ip>:5000 from your machine itslef to make sure app is running or not

Comment: I can access localhost:5000 but using this <your ip>:5000 i cant.

Comment: How do i get my ip? m using ip form : Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:-> IPv4 Address: XX.XX.XXX.XXX(Preferred).

Comment: goto command prompt, type 'ipconfig'

Comment: yeah did that but from which section i need to pick IPV4 address ? there are Ethernet adapter vEthernet and Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi and so on

Comment: Ethernet adapter vEthernet

Comment: Yeah using that but still getting same .This site can’t be reached

Comment: Try the sample code as well. Its working for me

Comment: "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address" got this error by changing localhost to 0.0.0.0

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38849252/sqlalchemy-exc-operationalerror-psycopg2-operationalerror

Comment: `my_ip:5000` from the same computer works but doesn't work from another computer in the same network.

Answer (score 2):

To access a Flask app from another machine, you need the app to bind to 0.0.0.0 instead of localhost (127.0.0.1). The latter won't route to another machine.

If you're running the app via python, use `run(host='0.0.0.0')`.

If you're running the app the `flask run`, add `--host=0.0.0.0`

Comment: "sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address" got this error by changing localhost to 0.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You can simply type the IP address of the host into your browser with the specified port number and you're good to go as both the computers are in the same network.

Answer (score -1):

Might be easier to just make it public temporarily: https://ngrok.com/

But would be even easier to do your testing locally from the same machine.